# El JSON me da un error de: Unexpected token 'a', "array(1) {"... is not valid JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

Existen más de 30 INPUT, todos type="color", entonces el ciclo antes del envio en javascript es para recopilar dichos datos.

PHP 8.0
JQUERY 3.7.0

Fragmento de PHP

```
<form id="frm_config" action="" method="POST">
<div class="contactos-general">
    <div class="contactos">
        <div class='btn_chat color_btn1'>
            <a href="">General</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grupos">
        <div class='btn_chat color_btn2'>
            <a href="">Friend!!!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cuador_interno">
    <div class="alinear_detalle">
        <input type="hidden" name="f_objeto_1" id="f_objeto_1" value="">
        <input type="color" class="format_input" value="#000000" id="objeto_1" name="objeto_1">
        <label for="objeto_1" class="separacion">Fondo de pantallas</label>
    </div>
    <div class="alinear_detalle">
        <input type="hidden" name="f_objeto_2" id="f_objeto_2" value="">
        <input type="color" class="format_input" value="#a4b4a3" id="objeto_2" name="objeto_2">
        <label for="objeto_2" class="separacion">Fondo de Formularios</label>
    </div>
    <div class="alinear_detalle">
        <input type="hidden" name="f_objeto_3" id="f_objeto_3" value="">
        <input type="color" class="format_input" value="#ffffff" id="objeto_3" name="objeto_3">
        <label for="objeto_3" class="separacion">Letras del menú</label>
    </div>
    <div class="alinear_detalle">
        <input type="hidden" name="f_objeto_4" id="f_objeto_4" value="">
        <input type="color" class="format_input" value="#094901" id="objeto_4" name="objeto_4">
        <label for="objeto_4" class="separacion">Letras al posicionarse</label>
    </div>
    <div class="alinear_detalle">
        <input type="hidden" name="f_objeto_5" id="f_objeto_5" value="_letras_titulo">
        <input type="color" class="format_input" value="#ffffff" id="objeto_5" name="objeto_5">
        <label for="objeto_5" class="separacion">Letra de Título</label>
    </div>
    <div class="alinear_detalle">
        <input type="hidden" name="f_objeto_6" id="f_objeto_6" value="_label_head">
        <input type="color" class="format_input" value="#057701" id="objeto_6" name="objeto_6">
        <label for="objeto_6" class="separacion">Cabecera del Formulario</label>
    </div>
    <div class="alinear_detalle">
        <input type="hidden" name="f_objeto_7" id="f_objeto_7" value="_label_food">
        <input type="color" class="format_input" value="#057701" id="objeto_7" name="objeto_7">
        <label for="objeto_7" class="separacion">Pie del Formulario</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fragmento de Javascript

```
function guardar_cambios() {
var jsonData = { objeto: "objeto" };
$("#frm_config input[type=color]").each(function () {
    jsonData[this.name] = this.value;
});

$.ajax({
    url: "view/soporte/save_change.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        objeto: jsonData
    }
})
.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
        console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente." );
    }
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
        console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
        console.log( errorThrown  );
    }
});
```

}

Observaciones por Consola:

La solicitud a fallado: parsererror
scripts.js:446 SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'a', "array(1) {"... is not valid JSON
at parse ()
at ajaxConvert (jquery-3.7.0.js:9089:19)
at done (jquery-3.7.0.js:9567:15)
at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.7.0.js:9878:9)

No tengo idea de que pasa. Sin embargo como todo es dinamico, es decir lo formulación del Formulario es a partir de los datos almacenados en tablas. Cada vez que se crea un nuevo elemento susceptible a cambios, es incorporado al mismo.

De antemano, les doy las gracias por prestar atención a mi requerimiento.

Comment: Te está diciendo que save_change.php no te está respondiendo un json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analisemos esta parte:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "view/soporte/save_change.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        objeto: jsonData
    }
})
```

Primero 2 recomendaciones

1. Usas `GET` yo te recomendaría usar `POST` para tu caso
2. Haces `data: {objeto: jsonData}`, envuelves tu objeto en otro objeto, esto sobra, debería ser simplemente `data`: jsonData`

Tu problema esta en:

3. `dataType: "json"` Aqui le dices que tu RESPUESTA será un JSON y eso no es así

Es decir en el PHP deberías usar `json_encode` en algún lado para imprimir el retorno.

Según tu mensaje de error, tu estas haciendo algo asi:

```
echo $array;
```

y Debería ser

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Ahora bien, tu no estas usando la respuesta del servidor para nada, solo imprimes por consola un mensaje "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente.", por lo que perfectamente tambien puedes hacer:

```
`dataType: "text"`
```

Con lo cual indica que la respuesta solo será un texto plano y jQuery no "parseará" la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por tan acertada respuesta. Realice los ajustes pertinentes.